# Danish residency, what are my options for studying in my home country?

Tags: immigration, eu, residency, uk-citizens, denmark

I am a British citizen with Danish residency (obtained before brexit), I have been living in Denmark. My partner is Danish and I live with them.

I am considering studying a degree, and it feels like my only option, if I want to study in the next 1-2 years, is to study in the UK because I can get a student loan. It is much more expensive to study a degree in Denmark as a non-EU citizen. I haven't been here long enough to obtain permanent residency which would help with cost.

I don't know if I will do it, I just want to know my options before considering it and deciding.

I know the residency rules are that I must be in Denmark at least 6 months of the year, and if you stay out of Denmark for longer than that, you must let Danish immigration know and it depends on the situation how they respond.

The degree would be 3 years. I worked out that, per year, it would be around 6.5-7 months. So likely up to 7 months out of each 12. Do you think I would have a chance to retain my residency, if I went back (to Denmark) for the other 5-6 months of the year? I would already be coming back often as my partner is Danish. After the degree finished, I would move fully back to Denmark.

**Can anyone advise me about this?** I don't know if there's legal issues of doing it, like maybe it's not allowed to reside two places in one year? If it meant I would lose my residency, I likely won't do it.

I want to contact the immigration people about it, but I am not sure how to go about asking them this, in case they misunderstand and think I am not taking the residency seriously. As said, I don't want to lose it. Any advice?

Comment: Frame challenge - how far away are you from obtaining permanent residency, perhaps based on provision of the EU withdrawal agreement (5 years) or meeting all 4 supplementary requirements (4 years)?

Comment: How the start date is made may be country specific, but the time spent before 2020-12-31 counts towards the 5 years to recieve permanent residence. In Germany, the date when you first registered your residence is what counts. If this was before 2020-12-31, that time is considered legal residence and will be added to the time you have had a residence permit after 2020. Since this rule is based on the [Withdrawal Agreement](https://commission.europa.eu/strategy-and-policy/relations-non-eu-countries/relations-united-kingdom/eu-uk-withdrawal-agreement/citizens-rights_en), you should look into this

Comment: For Denmark: [Coming to Denmark to work for 3 months or longer](https://skat.dk/data.aspx?oid=2246935) *... you need to apply for a CPR number at the Danish National Register (Folkeregisteret).* will probably be the date where the 5 year waiting period starts.

Comment: To all - I have found that, there is something called 'dispensation' which says you can apply for and it can be granted for up to 3 years. I just don't know if it would apply to me, a person with a withdrawal agreement based residency permit? 
https://www.nyidanmark.dk/en-GB/Your-situation-is-changing/Work/Lapse-dispensation
The terms it can be granted for are things like work, studies, serving in the military, but it quite vague. I tried to find this same page, within the EU residency pages, and the Brexit related pages on their website, and came up empty. So not sure it would apply for me?

Comment: @MarkJohnson thank you for your reply. I have looked into it and it seems it might be different than how I understood it, I will have to look into it more and ask about it.

Comment: Periods of residence before the withdrawal definitely do count towards permanent residence and that's not up to each country (to the extent that there are differences, the country would be in breach of the withdrawal agreement). The agreement spells this out in great details in article 16.

Comment: Higher education is free of charge for EU citizens.  Surely the preservation of rights under the withdrawal agreement means that it is also free of charge for those with residence under the withdrawal agreement before they obtain the right of permanent residence.

Comment: @phoog I was thinking the same but there is a very convoluted sentence in article 23(2) of the withdrawal agreement that creates some exceptions to the general principle of equal treatment. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @Relaxed [These notes from a Danish ministry (esp. the financial support)](https://ufm.dk/en/brexit) seems to agree with what you and phoog are expecting.

Comment: @raindrops In light of the new information above in the comments, I recommend you to look into your current fee status in Denmark first, then your eligibility for Danish permanent residence and everything else. Of course, I am not saying the questions you have is invalid in anyway, but the text gives the impression that you prefer to study in Denmark and your current line of investigation may be an unnecessarily difficult path.

Comment: @B.Liu in a comment on the [other question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/26639/2440) raindrops indicates that there may be other reasons for preferring to study in the UK, so the question would still be meaningful even in light of the possibility of tuition-free study in Denmark.